# How can I add the version number to the path using Laravel Mix?

Tags: css, laravel, cdn, laravel-mix

I am using Laravel Mix to compile my JS and CSS assets.  I'm currently using `.version()` to achieve this.

The problem is that this produces a file similar to:

`/css/app.css?id=03def6a69840076e8f29`

That works fine when serving it locally, but if I'm using a CDN to serve this content via an origin pull then the query string doesn't force a new pull of the file.  Ideally I'd like the following instead:

`/css/03def6a69840076e8f29/app.css`

Or:

`/css/03def6a69840076e8f29.css`

Both of these are different files, so it forces a pull on the CDN.

How can this be achieved with Laravel Mix?

Comment: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/934

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, and came up with the solution:

1. Add the following line to `public/.htaccess`:

   `RewriteRule ^assets/[a-f0-9]+/(.*)$ /$1 [L]`

right before `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

this will treat urls like `/assets/ab7320d/css/whatever.css` as `/css/whatever.css`

2. Put the following code to `resources/assets/js/rewriteMixManifest.js`

   ```
   let fs = require('fs')
   let mixManifestPath = `${process.cwd()}/public/mix-manifest.json`
   let mixFileContents = fs.readFileSync(mixManifestPath)
   let oldMapping = JSON.parse(mixFileContents)
   function updateMapping(path) {
       if(path.indexOf("?") < 1) {
           return path
       }
       let [filename, idPart] = path.split("?")
       let [_, id] = idPart.split("=")
       return `/assets/${id}${filename}`
   }
   let newContent = {}
   for(let file in oldMapping) {
       newContent[file] = updateMapping(oldMapping[file])
   }
   console.log("Manifest rewritten.")
   fs.writeFileSync(mixManifestPath, JSON.stringify(newContent, null, 2))
   ```
3. In `package.json`, add the following line in `scripts` (just like "dev" key)

   ```
   "rewrite-manifest": "node resources/assets/js/rewriteMixManifest.js",
   ```
4. After each build (e.g. `npm run production`) also run `npm run rewrite-manifest`

So what `public/mix-manifest.json` file does is it maps each assets file (for `{{ mix('css/app.css') }}`) to some string that will actually go to HTML. My script rewrites the string to put version not to query string, but to the path. `.htaccess` makes sure the path is interpreted right.

The path structure is of course up to you to change to your liking

For me it solved the problem with Google Cloud CDN, hope it helps you too

Answer (score -1):

You can try calling the asset this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
```

Comment: That just outputs the app.css file with a version appended as a query string.  I need it part of the path to allow for origin-pull CDNs.